# For loop can 'see' forthcoming values in current iteration?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, iteration, charat

I am working my way through CodingBat's Java exercises and I came across the [CountXX problem](http://codingbat.com/prob/p194667), which counts the amount of times *xx* appears in a string. Here is how I solved it (I wasn't expecting it to work):

```
int countXX(String str) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {

        if ((str.charAt(i) == 'x') && (str.charAt(i+1) == 'x'))
            count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

My question is: How is an iteration of a for loop able to 'look ahead' to the next iteration? In this case, it is able to see the value of one character *and* the following iteration's character. If it can look ahead to future iterations, doesn't that 'defeat the point' of incrementing by integer? (I am certainly missing something!)

Comment: `For` loop is for doing a loop until a condition met, it does not 'look' anywhere. You just use it to control range in which `i` can change, and then you calculate _another_ range you must check inside a string (that another range consists of two elements: `i` and `i+1`).

Comment: Think of it this way: You are iterating using some index. That's it. Your loop is just an index `i` which increases until it reaches some limit. What you do inside the loop is completely your decision. You can use that index `i` to do anything. You can use `i` however you want! You can use `2 * i` for `i * i` or, in your case, `i + 1` to get the next character. Your approach is perfectly fine. The loop itself doesn't "see" anything. It just provides a construct for you to have a consistently increasing index `i` to use how you want. That's the way you want to think of these things goin forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iteration is not "looking ahead" or anything like that. In fact, the `for` loop has no idea that you are iterating over indexes of a string. All it knows is that you want it to

- Set `i = 0` before starting the iteration
- End the iteration when `i` becomes greater than a certain number, and
- Increment `i` by `1` after each iteration.

That's about it. Any interpretation of `i` variable as an index into the string is done inside the body of the loop.

Once inside the loop, you can count on `i` to be in a certain range (namely, from zero, inclusive, to `str.length() - 1`, exclusive). This makes `i` a suitable candidate to obtain two adjacent characters from a string, which is precisely what your code does.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if ((str.charAt(i) == 'x') && (str.charAt(i+1) == 'x'))
                                            ^
```

You tell him to see one character ahead.

Comment: I understand that...but my point is that it is able to see the next character in the string on the current iteration it is on (I find it difficult to explain.)

Comment: @alanbuchanan: you can see *all* characters in every iteration step if you wish. A `String` is a random access structure. You may call `charAt(arbitraryIndex)` even without a loop.

Comment: @alanbuchanan I don't know what you exactly mean, but `i+1` does not increment your current loop if that is the question..

Answer (score 1):

Simply because you use the `charAt` at the current index + 1 :

```
if ((str.charAt(i) == 'x') && (str.charAt(i+1) == 'x'))
```

> If it can look ahead to future iterations, doesn't that 'defeat the
>   point' of incrementing by integer?

Since you are looking for the number of time the sequence `xx` appear in the string, you need to check for the current, and the next character which is why the algorithm look ahead.

It does not *defeat the point of incrementing by integer*. If you would want to do it with an other algorithm, you would have to create a temporary variable which hold the last character, or a counter. IMHO it is way simplier that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new, the only silly question is the one you didn't ask :)

The key is this line: `((str.charAt(i) == 'x') && (str.charAt(i+1) == 'x'))`
Basically, at each iteration, it's checking both element i and element i+1.

This doesn't defeat the point of iterating 1 at a time; it will check 0 and 1, then 1 and 2, then 2 and 3, and so on; if we incremented by 2 each time, then we'd miss the case where there were two x's in a row, but the first one was in an odd-numbered position (i.e. "abcxxdef").

As mentioned above, you'll need to stop one position earlier (at str.length()-1), because the second half of the expression adds 1 to the idex, which would push it out of bounds and cause an exception.

Comment: I understand the line you quoted and the concept of a for loop. I think I didn't explain my question well enough.

Answer (score 0):

***Note:*** I understand that this is not a complete answer to the question; see it as an addition to the other answers.

A for-loop can always be refactored to an infinite loop with a break condition and a counter statement*:

```
//for(/*initializer*/; /*break condition*/; /*end statement*/) { /*body statement block*/ }
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    /* do something */
}
```

equals:

```
{
    int i = 0;
    while(true) {
        if(i < length) {
            break;
        }
        /* do something */
        i++;
    }
}
```

---

*not necessarily, instead of `i++` it could be any statement such as `System.out.println("foo")` and even more than just one. But that's beyond every-day usage.